# How to execute a target when generic files exist

Tags: build, msbuild

I am using `msbuild` for my project and need to have a target execute only if, in a certain locations, a whatever text file exists.

My file is:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MYFolder>C:\myfolder\</MYFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <TXTFiles Include="$(MYFolder)*.scss"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Condition="???"></Target>
</Project>
```

### What I tried

This:

```
Condition="!Exists('@(TXTFiles ->'%(FullPath)')')"
```

But it does not work.

This:

```
Condition="!Exists('@(TXTFiles)')"
```

But it does not work.

What condition can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try make condition on the count of items and execute target if count is greater than zero or non-equal to zero.

```
Condition=" '0' != '@(TXTFiles->Count())' "
```

or

```
Condition=" '0' &lt; '@(TXTFiles->Count())' "
```

Symbol < must be escaped in xml.